# Entering Unicode characters by name

Tags: x11, unicode, user-interface, input-method

Emacs has the `insert-char` feature: You press a key combination and get a menu containing all Unicode characters with search similar to `dmenu` and most DE's program launchers.

For example, to enter "∃" (THERE EXISTS), I type `<Ctrl-x> 8 <Enter> exists <Enter>`.

Is there something similar that works in all X11 programs?

Comment: You can use ibus with addon ibus-unicode-db , from github .

Answer (score 1):

I would think Autokey would do the job as described [here](https://brushingupscience.wordpress.com/2015/12/28/add-any-symbol-without-leaving-the-keyboard/). The idea is that Autokey is always running and can accept arbitrary strings as triggers.

As the post describes, you just need to set up Autokey to paste unicode characters and as a trigger it could accept something like /delta, which it then replaces with a δ.

Answer (score 0):

My feeling is that this is out of the X11 scope, this is desktop environtment business.

For KDE, `kcharselect` is a tool to pick special characters, including search. It should fit your needs, if you put it on a global shortcut key like I did. Drawback: The chars get copied to the paste buffer, so you need one more keystroke to insert them.

Comment: Obviously I don't want such a tool to be part of the X server, but it should work in all graphical programs.

Comment: @Eric Well, that's the case for `kcharselect` for all graphical programs that support the clipboard (which almost all do, I guess).

Comment: This is input method business. Input methods are mostly independent of desktop environments.